# JS to Play video in native player on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, video, mobile-safari, jwplayer

I'm creating the responsive version of my website. There are a couple of videos.
At the moment, I use jwPlayer. That's fine on the full-size version and on iPads.
On iPhone, I get the 2 step behavior (Showing the video player just with the poster, and opening the native video player when launching the video.)

Is there a way to automatically (with some Javascript perhaps) load the video on the native video player? So JWplayer shouldn't even start at all...

In the end, User Experience would be : clicking on a thumbnail ->iOs video player ->back to thumbnails.

Is this possible?

Comment: For small screen iOS devices, once play is pressed, the video will play in the full screen iOS video player. With the JW Player though, it will always load our shell first, then once play is pressed, the default iOS player takes over.

Comment: I know, That's the behavior now, I'm looking for a way to void this in-between step, clicking on the thumbnails should open the video in the native player.

Comment: What you could do is try to use our API to load() content, then play() it - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31800/loading-new-playlists, however, there needs to be a player instance already present on the page first for this to work.